# How to take sql server database backup till a perticular date?

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

In our project there are two databases

```
  1)Transactional 
  2)Warehouse.
```

Based on some retention timeout the data will be pushed from Transactional to Warehouse DB.So now i want to `take the backup of the Transactional DB backup till a particular date`. is it possible? or is there any better way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the type of database - datawarehouse or transactional;

There are two ways you can perform a backup - HOT and COLD
HOT - the database is up when you perform the backup
COLD - the database is not available when you perform the backup

There are two types of backup you can perform - FULL and INCREMENTAL
I general prefer the following strategy

Create a FULL backup on a weekly basis and an INCREMENTAL backup on a daily basis
Backup the database log on a hourly (based on your requirement) basis - this is only for transaction database

if the version of your database allows the backup HOT, go ahead and do it; if not you will need a cold backup
Also, after completing the datawarehouse take a full load.